# How to tell if AWS Lambda functions are hitting memory or duration limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory-management, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I tell from the AWS Cloudwatch console if my AWS Lambda functions are hitting any memory or duration limits and getting terminated? I created some alarms for memory usage and they appear to periodically go past my maximum memory allocation, but I’m not seeing anything indicating that they were terminated as a result of memory usage?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html "Performance testing your Lambda function is a crucial part in ensuring you pick the optimum memory size configuration. Any increase in memory size triggers an equivalent increase in CPU available to your function. The memory usage for your function is determined per-invoke and can be viewed in AWS CloudWatch Logs. On each invoke a REPORT: entry will be made, as shown below:"

Comment: CloudWatch metrics for your Lambdas will aggregate errors. CloudWatch Insights might help you to identify timeouts vs. out of memory exceptions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-access-metrics.html

Comment: @jarmod oh, thanks, I followed your link to this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html and I am seeing that the `Errors` metric includes: Handled exceptions (for example, context.fail(error)), Unhandled exceptions causing the code to exit, *Out of memory exceptions*, *Timeouts*, Permissions errors. It looks like I can monitor that metric for such errors!